# Как создать адаптивную «‎плитку»‎ в css (bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

Необходимо сделать плитку по два залитых краской квадратика 50/50 с отцентрированным текстом:

[image]

В bootstrap стоят две колонки col-xs-6, но как сделать что бы высота менялась пропорционально ширине и что бы текст соответственно тоже центрировался относительно размеров плитки?

Answer (score 2):

Тут есть несколько вариантов решения (как минимум два), вариант с помощью css:
1. каждой колонке присваиваете выравнивание текста по центру text-align: center;
2. в примере снизу не совсем удачно, что текст, но у вас судя по всему фиксированный контент с иконками и проблем быть не должно. на колонки назначаете padding: ?vw 0 ?vw 0;. на месте вопросов ставите значения подобранные методом научного тыка :) (в плане подбираете чтобы изображение центрировалось, в браузере это делается без проблем)
3. при необходимости на некоторых разрешениях с помощью @media запросов корректируете эти padding.

```
<div  style="background: red;">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: aqua; text-align: center; padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;">В bootstrap стоят две колонки col-xs-6, но как сделать что бы высота менялась пропорционально</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: aquamarine; text-align: center;padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;">В bootstrap стоят две колонки col-xs-6, но как сделать что бы высота менялась пропорционально</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: beige; text-align: center;padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;">В bootstrap стоят две колонки col-xs-6, но как сделать что бы высота менялась пропорционально</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: blueviolet; text-align: center;padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;">В bootstrap стоят две колонки col-xs-6, но как сделать что бы высота менялась пропорционально</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: aquamarine; text-align: center;padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;">В bootstrap стоят две колонки col-xs-6, но как сделать что бы высота менялась пропорционально</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: cyan; text-align: center;padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;">В bootstrap стоят две колонки col-xs-6, но как сделать что бы высота менялась пропорционально</div>
```

второй метод завязан на jQuery, но он сложнее и топорнее. при необходимости могу потом примерно описать логику

Comment: зачем использовать jquery, если можно сделать все на основе bootstrap и нативном css?

Comment: поэтому и не описывал, просто есть вариант если заняться нечем :). не надо ставить рамок, надо иметь свободу маневра)

Comment: С выравниваием понял, а как сделать так, что бы высота залитой определенным цветом col-xs-6 - равнялась ее ширине, образуя квадрат? Если на глаз выставлять vh, то при изменении экрана - высота начинает разнится с шириной и пропорции квадрата пропадают (выравненный по центру текст тоже вылетает если просто vh стоит).

Comment: 1vw = 1% от ширины окна. При уменьшении ширины окна, уменьшается ширина, высота, шрифт элемента.
1vh = 1% от высоты окна. При уменьшении высоты окна, уменьшается ширина, высота, шрифт элемента.
используйте vw в padding, должно получиться :).